# Change face instance orientation

Tags: faces, instances, transform-orientation

I'm trying to use the face instancing workflow, but I would like to rotate the instance orientation for some of the instancer faces.

Using Alt+N (flip) will rotate the instance orientation 90 degrees, but I'd like to be able to rotate the instances on this face 180 degrees in this instance.

Is there a way to explicitly set or edit face instance orientation?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand **[the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/faces.html#limitations-considerations)**, when a face is created, its vertices are indexed on a per-face basis (not the same as the vertex indices for the whole mesh).

Contrarily to the mesh-wide vertex indices, These are not accessible or modifiable.

In other words, your only solution is to rotate each face by whatever multiple of 90° and then use the modeling tools to get back the original shape and ratio of the face.

Or, as suggested in the manual, restart your modeling and use face duplication instead of edge extrusion or some other operator in order to get more predictable results, and display the instances while modeling so you don't get surprised later.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried digging a little deeper and the face rotation seemed to be the best way to directly modify the instance rotation. 

In this case I was really hoping that the manual was falling short of the current implementation, but it's very well documented! 

Thanks for pointing me in the direction of the per face vs mesh wide vertex indicies. I was not aware of this and I think I need to do some reading about those data structures.